# How to show a file updated constantly on the browser?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My goal is to update the web page with some file. When I edit and save the file, and instantly its content appears updated to a page.

I´m using **socket.io** to handle this issue. But. I need some modifications on my code to approaches it.

:: My server side code:

```
var PORT = 8001;
var io = require("socket.io").listen(PORT);
var fs = require("fs");

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connected!");
    socket.emit('connected', { accept: true});

    console.log("Trying to send a content file to client...");
    fs.readFile("file.txt","UTF-8", function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        socket.emit("requestFile", data );
        console.log("Conteúdo:", data);
    })
});

console.log("Application has started! Port: " + PORT);
```

:: My page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            .arquivo {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                width: 900px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("Try to logon...");
            var socket = io.connect("localhost", {"port" : "8001"});

            socket.on("connected", function(data) {
                console.log("Connected User?", data.accept);
            });

            //recebe o arquivo indefinidamente
            var requestFile = socket.on("requestFile", function(data) {
                $("#arquivoSaida").html(data + "<br/>");
                console.log(data);
            });

            setInterval(requestFile, 200);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 style="font: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
            File updated:
        </h3>
        <div id="arquivoSaida">

        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used a setInterval to fires at 200 ms to request a file to a server. Any cue will be very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

**-- UPDATED with Solution:**

:: I did some alterations from my original code. This solution was provided by PuerkitoBio. Thanks, man!

The code updated:

```
var PORT = 8001;
var io = require("socket.io").listen(PORT);
var fs = require("fs");

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connected!");
    socket.emit('connected', { accept: true});

    console.log("Trying to send the content to a client...");
    console.log("dir", __dirname);

    fs.watch(__dirname + "/arquivo.txt", function(event, filename) {
        console.log("Event:", event);

        if (event == "change") {
            fs.readFile("arquivo.txt","UTF-8", function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                socket.emit("receiveFile", data );
                console.log("Content:", data);
            })
        }

    });

});

console.log("Application has started! Port: " + PORT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fs.watchFile()` and compare curr.mtime with prev.mtime to detect if the file has been modified. Then use readFile to send the content to your connected client. [From the docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html).

With sockets, you don't poll the data from the client, it gets pushed from the server when required (when your file changes, in your case). So you don't need the setInterval from the client side (you will watch for changes server-side using fs.watchFile, and push the content to your client, so your "requestFile" handler on the client will get called automatically (should be renamed receiveFile or something to be more accurate!).

Comment: Thanks, PuerkitoBio. I toke a look about you told me and I fixed the code. I´ve been using fs.watch instead of fs.watchFile, it´s the recommendation way to accomplish it. Take a look above to see my modification.

Comment: Looks good to me, I suppose you adapted the client side accordingly. If the file content is big, you may want to consider streaming it (take a look at node's Stream class). Other than that, this should work fine.